# how do I interact with a smart contract deployed on the ropsten test network?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I have already deployed a contract on the ropsten test network and also have the contract address.

But, How do I interact with it through something like an android project?

I know I have to add the dependencies first and all. But, here's the confusion -

I have deployed the contract on **etherscan's** ropsten testnet through the remix IDE

Deployed a project on **infura**

Created a **metamask** wallet which now has 1 eth on the ropsten testnet

now, how do I combine all this such that I can access it in my android studio or any other project for that matter?

All I need is to know how anybody would interact with a contract.

Even getting to know the basic requirements steps would be more than enough.

### Any help will be appriciated...

its getting harder and harder to find answers on the net and I don't have much time. Appriciate the help, thank you...

Comment: There are mobile versions of MetaMask ([docs](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/mobile-getting-started.html)) and WalletConnect ([docs](https://docs.walletconnect.com/mobile-linking)). I don't know how to emulate these in the Android studio, but at least the docs should help you. It seems to be similar approach to interacting with their browser versions - i.e. calling a local API published by the app/extension and requesting the user to confirm/deny an action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow found a [blog with a Github sample project](https://blog.jayway.com/2017/08/23/interacting-with-ethereum-smart-contracts-from-android/) which is simple enough to figure out what does what inside the project.

**It is an extremely simple hello world project.**

If you are like me and haven't been able to make any progress for the past 4-6 hours because of lack of info, then this will surely help.

#### here's the [Github Link](https://github.com/noev/Android-Ethereum-Hello-World) if you are in a hurry.